# ROS,Tiago gmapping many erros & warnings

Tags: ros, navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I start to work with Tiago and my first task is autonomous navigation.
But I got many warnings and error by following the Tiago-Tutorials in Wiki-Ros.
My workstation is running with ROS-Indigo.

**Executed command:**
droid@M6600:~/tiago_public_ws$ roslaunch tiago_2dnav_gazebo tiago_mapping_public.launch

**Warnings**:

- The complete state of the robot is not yet known.  Missing gripper_left_finger_joint, gripper_right_finger_joins
- TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame odom at time 135.951 according to authority unknown_publisher

**@TF_OLD_DATA**

Set the following line in 'tiago_mapping_public.launch', without any success. 
param name ="/use_sim_time" value="true"/

Then set the parameter with 'rosparam set use_sim_time true' without any success.
Still recieve the warning.

**@ gripper_left_finger_joint, gripper_right_finger_joins**

Can not understand this message?
Why is the robot(tiago) state not known?

**Error 1:**
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1507279517.616354] [0.000000] Failed to load joint_state_controller
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1507279517.912537] [0.000000] Failed to load imu_sensor_controller
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1507279517.912547] [0.000000] Failed to load gripper_controller

**Error 2:**

ERROR [1507272826.100795595, 142.018000000]: Joint 'hand_index_abd_joint' not found in model 'tiago' 
ERROR [1507272826.100850983, 142.018000000]: Joint 'hand_index_flex_1_joint' not found in model 'tiago' 
ERROR [1507272826.100881901, 142.018000000]: Joint 'hand_index_flex_2_joint' not found in model 'tiago'  
ERROR [1507272826.100915909, 142.018000000]: Joint 'hand_index_flex_3_joint' not found in model 'tiago' 
ERROR [1507272826.100947619, 142.019000000]: Joint 'hand_index_joint' not found in model 'tiago' 
ERROR [1507272826.100975658, 142.019000000]: Joint 'hand_index_virtual_1_joint' not found in model 'tiago' 
ERROR [1507272826.101006027, 142.019000000]: Joint 'hand_index_virtual_2_joint' not found in model 'tiago' 
ERROR [1507272826.101036851, 142.019000000]: Joint 'hand_index_virtual_3_joint' not found in model 'tiago' 
ERROR [1507272826.101064825, 142.019000000]: Joint 'hand_little_abd_joint' not found in model 'tiago' 
ERROR [1507272826.101089220, 142.019000000]: Joint 'hand_little_flex_1_joint' not found in model 'tiago' 
ERROR [1507272826.101112872, 142.019000000]: Joint 'hand_little_.......................

How can I fix this errors?

If I ignore all the warnings and errors, I can still start with mapping.

**Error 3:**
By saving the map with :

droid@M6600:~/tiago_public_ws$ rosservice call /pal_map_manager/save_map  "directory: '3XC12'"

I got the following message:

**ERROR: Unable to load type [pal_navigation_msgs/SaveMap].

Have you typed 'make' in [pal_navigation_msgs]?**

Bevor starting with mapping, I already execute 'catkin build', with the result:

[build] Summary: All 82 packages    succeeded!
[build]   Ignored:   8 packages were skipped or are blacklisted.
[build]   Warnings:  None.
[build]   Abandoned: None.
[build]   Failed:    None.
[build] Runtime: 32.3 seconds total.

Therefore the type 'pal_navigation_msgs' must be available on my local workstation !?!

**Error 4:**

Sometimes after rebooting or starting Tiago in web-commander under 'Diagnostics'
I got the following error:

Full Name: /Functionality/Startup control/mm11_cfg
Message: Crashed
cmd: rosrun mm11_cfg_tiago mm11_cfg.py
log_file: /tmp/ros_logs/b683d704-aa6f-11e7-82e9-305a3a561cca//mm11_cfg-1.pal.log
dependencies: Hardware: MM11 Hardware: Sonar

Restarting the service doesn't fix the error, I have to restart Tiago with 'shutdown -r now'.

Dont know how to fix all the errors & warnings

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272433/ros,tiago-gmapping-many-erros-&-warnings/) by [Jabo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32160/jabo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Fix the problem with saving the map on Tiago (Error 3).**

But the warnings and the errors (1&2) are still present !!

---

Originally posted by [Jabo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32160/jabo/) with karma: 16 on 2017-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Neil](https://answers.ros.org/users/41036/neil/) on 2019-05-07**:
How did you fix the problem ?, I am getting the same problem.
ERROR: Service [/pal_map_manager/save_map] is not available.

**Comment by [Booooyaaaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/62393/booooyaaaa/) on 2022-04-26**:
I solved it by catkin build and source /devel/setup.bash